# How to enable FTP on W2008 R2 SP1 for a user who are allowed to "Log on as a service"

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp, windows-firewall

I am able to download files from an FTP on Win-CE to W2008 R2 SP1 64-Bit with a batch after creating a Firewall rule:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow FTP" dir=in action=allow profile=private program="C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe" enable=yes
```

The user is a member of the group "Administrators".

Unfortunately the above is not true for a user who are allowed to "Log on as a service".

The only "solution" - is to turn off the Firewall for the "Private Network".

The same downloading script works fine on W2003,WXP and W7 Professional 32 and 64-Bits, when invoked by a member of the group "Administrators" or a member of the same group, who are set "Log on as a service".

Answer (score 0):

Run far far away.

- Windows: may be secure
- FTP: insecure
- FTP as Administrator: more insecure
- FTP as Administrator with disabled firewall on a server: evil